# Differences in simple proguard keep option

Tags: java, proguard

What is the difference between these two proguard options?

```
 -keep class com.myclass.**
 -keep class com.myclass.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first rule will only keep the **classes** themselves (and the default constructors).

The second rule will also keep all **methods** and **fields** in the classes.

Answer (score 1):

```
-keep class com.myclass.**
```

Preserve all classes in the `com.myclass` package and any sub-packages. Even if shrinking and optimization steps should alter the structure of or remove these classes, do not do so.

```
-keep class com.myclass.** { *; }
```

Preserve all classes in the `com.myclass` package as defined above as well as all fields and methods in those classes.

An example of the difference: With the first command, my entry point methods (such as `main`) can still be shrunk, optimized, and obfuscated. In order to keep the signatures of those methods intact, I can specify the methods or fields I need to keep (or just the wildcard `*` as you did, though I would think that's too broad). This is essential for reflection and other situations where signatures and names must be kept intact.

Note that `-keepnames` and similar commands also keep the signatures, but only if they weren't already removed during shrinking.