# What's the difference between -keep class com.sample.Foo {*;} and -keep class com.sample.Foo?

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation

I just built two release APKs.

One of them had

```
-keep class com.sample.Foo
```

And the other had

```
-keep class com.sample.Foo {*;}
```

When I decompiled the app on http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk, `Foo` was the same for both builds.

The code of `Foo` is below:

```
package com.sample;

import android.util.Log;

public class Foo {

    public int field;

    public Foo() {
        field = 90;
    }

    public int doSth() {
        doPrivate();
        return 2 * field;
    }

    private void doPrivate() {
        Log.d("Proguard", "doPrivate");
    }

    void doDef() {
        Log.d("Proguard", "doDef");
    }
}
```

That's how I made sure `Foo` and its methods weren't obfuscated:

```
package com.sample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.sample.Foo");
            Object instance = aClass.newInstance();
            Method method = aClass.getMethod("doSth");
            Integer res = (Integer) method.invoke(instance);
            Log.d("Proguard", "doSth res=" + res);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Proguard", "", e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update #1**

My Proguard config.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences in simple proguard keep option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39747660/differences-in-simple-proguard-keep-option)

Comment: @T.Neidhart, they both kept methods

Comment: Then you have additional rules that are responsible for this.

Comment: @T.Neidhart, I had `-keep class com.sample.Foo {*;}` or `-keep class com.sample.Foo` in my `proguard-rules.pro`. Besides the default rules from `sdk\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt` were included. See update #1

Comment: Then ProGuard might have kept the doSth and doPrivate methods as it could determine their use via reflection, as you used hard-coded strings for it. I guess the doDef method was removed?

Answer (score 0):

The first one only keeps the class and its constructor.

The second one keeps the class and its constructor and  any field or method inside the class.